# What counts as Crowd Control?

Tags: diablo-iv

Multiple legendary affixes refer to Crowd Controlled enemies:

> Becoming Injured while Crowd Controlled grants you Unstoppable for 4 seconds.

> Restore 1 of your Primary Resource when you Crowd Control an enemy.

Is there a clear way to know what constitutes "Crowd Control" and how to know when an enemy has been affected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Crowd Control is a common term for all negative effects (other than dealing damage or changing the amount of damage received) that can be placed on players or monsters.

Anything that causes the enemies to move at a slower speed will count, too. The rings secondary effect will count as a crowd control as well. Blind, stun, frozen, slowed, rooted are forms of crowd control.

According to [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Diablo/comments/2h4pbv/what_is_considered_crowd_control_with_regards_to/), if you open your inventory and click on Materials & Stats, click on the eye icon, go to Damage vs Crowd Controlled and it will show you a list of what is consider "crowd control".